# Generate table by VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA. I hope that this is not a difficult question for you.My problem:

I have TEXT in column A and NUMBER in column B. Like this:

```
Column A    Column B
TEXT 1      3
TEXT 2      2
TEXT 3      3
.....       ...
```

I need to auto-generate a table in other sheet which has two columns. First contains the text which repeats n times (NUMBER in column B) and then the next text from Column A. In the second column of this table I need number from 1 to NUMBER. like this:

```
Column A    Column B
TEXT 1      1
TEXT 1      2
TEXT 1      3
TEXT 2      1
TEXT 2      2
TEXT 3      1
TEXT 3      2
TEXT 3      3
....        ....
```

Then I have to post-process this table, but I know how to make it. I don't know how to generate the table.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The natural choice is to loop over the relevant cells in column A of the first sheet, while populating the two columns of the second sheet in an inner loop, maintaining a counter variable which points to the row in the second sheet where the next values are to be written.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment:

```
Sub MakeTable()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim t As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets(1).Activate
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row()

    k = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        t = Cells(i, 1).Value
        m = Cells(i, 2).Value
        For j = 1 To m
            ws.Cells(k, 1).Value = t
            ws.Cells(k, 2).Value = j
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes that the original data is in Sheet1 and you are transferring it to Sheet2, and that the data begins in row 1. Adjust accordingly if those assumptions are false. The way I determine the last cell in column A that has data is an important idiom in Excel VBA and should be mastered.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. It's working great. In fact, this is easy task, but I'm new in VBA. I know the MATLAB good so the table making (FOR loops) wasn't the issue. But the initial syntax of the code was. So thank you again.